# How to push new files of a project to an existing bitbucket repo

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bitbucket

I am working on a ASP.net MVC project and we have a bitbucket repository for it.

I cloned the project from bitbucket (with git bash) and then made some new files in it and added some pictures etc. I committed my changes locally and pushed it to the bitbucket (with tortoise git).

But now when I'm seeing the newest clone, there is just the name of file showing with that yellow box ("AHUController.cs") (no code in it).

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyWAH.png) (click this link)

and it is showing this error when I'm opening it-

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2rUR.png) (click this link)

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here or any other way to do it.

(step by step would be helpful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file (AHUController.cs) simply hasn't been included in your last pushed commit to your repository.

If you're starting out with git, there are only really a few things you need to know to cover most use-cases:

1. git clone (which you obviously have figured out)
2. after doing your work, cd to the base folder of your checkout, eg: if you used `git clone` to clone `https://github.com/someuser/someproject` so that you now have a folder `C:\users\yourname\projects\someproject`, then cd to `C:\users\yourname\projects\someproject`
3. Typically (at least for now), you'd like to commit all things, so first you add them with `git add -A :/`  (add all files from here down), then `git commit` (and you'll have to enter a commit message) and `git push`

If the CLI is being a bother (and it can be for some), check out GitKraken, a cross-platform, really good (imo) git client: http://gitkraken.com/

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't including the files at a point. just noticed it. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is one the tool used to commit bitbucket repositories.
Try if it helps you.

http://confiablesolutions.com/SetupSourceControl.aspx